# How to secure kafka topic for producer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, apache-kafka

I've multiple producers to push messages into my kafka broker. Want to secure my topic, so that producers need password to push messages in topic or any kind of protection.

In spring boot got to see below properties.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.[security.protocol]=SSL
#spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.[ssl.truststore.location]=D:\\streaming\\MessagingQueingTier\\SSL\\kafka.client.truststore.jks
#spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.[ssl.truststore.password]=clientpass
#spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.[ssl.keystore.location]=D:\\streaming\\MessagingQueingTier\\SSL\\kafka.client.keystore.jks
#spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.[ssl.keystore.password]=clientpass
#spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.[ssl.key.password]=clientpass
```

Are these properties useful to fulfill my requirment ? And How can I set these properties ?
Not able to understand. Can anyone help or share any reference doc to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to configure kafka to require the password or do you want spring to set / use that password or are you asking about both?

Comment: @luk2302, well am doing it first time, so I think set password from kafka side and spring app + producer should have that password to connect with topic and once connected then start pushing messages. isn't it a correct way ? will be helpful if you could also share your views on this to make stronger. :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer documentation of Kafka security. There are lot of way to secure Kafka:

- SASL
- SSL
- Custom

For authorization, there are different ways

- Apache Ranger
- Kafka inbuilt ACLs

Refer this [doc](https://medium.com/@stephane.maarek/introduction-to-apache-kafka-security-c8951d410adf)